# Entity Framework One to Optional One relationship

Tags: entity-framework-6, one-to-one

I've been trying to figure out how to create a one to optional one relationship in Entity Framework but everything I try seems to result in an exception or with the navigation properties not working correctly. Could anyone explain how to annotate the below so both objects can exist in the database and a link can optionally be made from one to the other?

Many thanks

```
public class ObjectA
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual ObjectB ObjectB { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectB
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual ObjectA ObjectA { get; set; }
    public int? ObjectAID { get; set; }

}
```

**Edit:**

With the code as it stands I get the following exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'Namespace.ObjectA' and 'Namespace.ObjectB'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose which entity will be a principal and which will be a dependent in this relationship. If it's true that `ObjectB` is dependent, then you could solve the problem with the following options:

1) **Data Annotations**. Mark `ObjectB`'s `ObjectAID` property with `RequiredAttribute`:

```
public class ObjectB
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual ObjectA ObjectA { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int? ObjectAID { get; set; }    
}
```

2) **Fluent API**. Configure Model Builder:

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ObjectB>().HasRequired(b => b.ObjectA).WithOptional(a => a.ObjectB);
    }
}
```